# Php Script update={$row['ID']}'>{$row['HEADING']} work only on local device database but not in cloud database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have two databases (cloud database and one in local device). 
All the other credentials username, password, database name are the same in all databases.

But the following piece of code

`echo "<b><a href='updatephp.php?update={$row['ID']}'>{$row['HEADING']}</a></b>";`

from php script below work only in database in local device but not in cloud database.

```
<?php
$db = "nhldb";
$user = "root";
$password = "password";
$host = "localhost";
$connection = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$password");
$db = mysqli_select_db("$db", $connection);
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['did'];
    $heading = $_GET['dheading'];
    $descr = $_GET['ddescr'];
    $story = $_GET['dstory'];
    $image = $_GET['dimage'];
    $url = $_GET['durl'];
    $reporter = $_GET['dreporter'];
    $category = $_GET['dcategory'];
    $query = mysqli_query("update home_db set
                     HEADING='$heading', STORY='$story', descr='$descr', category='$category',reporter='$reporter',url = '$url', IMAGE='$image' where ID='$id'", $connection);
}
$query = mysqli_query("select * from home_db ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10", $connection);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo "<b><a href='updatephp.php?update={$row['ID']}'>{$row['HEADING']}</a></b>";
   echo "<br />";
   echo "<hr />";
}
?>
```

Anyone to help Please!

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['submit']))` how does this even get triggered?

Comment: don't use `mysql_*` . you should used `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: @BilalAhmed in all query or in some queries?

Comment: first check you DB connection (credentials), second `mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password");` remove `"` like this `mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);`, and third upload form code

Comment: @BilalAhmed am i suporsed to use msqli_*   in all the queries or in some queries?

Comment: no. mysql_* is an unsecured but it's work fine

Comment: i have above mention 3 points. check Database connection, correct query and third show your form code

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @rndus2r it is triggered when i want to update the data which i have updated

Answer (score 2):

You are using mysql but it was deprecated in **PHP v5.5.0** and removed in **PHP v7**.

The reason why it is working in localhost is that your xampp is definately using **old version of php.**